# Breaker “shifted” under panel cover

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

One of the breakers in my panel has shifted out of position slightly (*#13 in the image*).

This happened as I was turning it off. I am unable to shift it back into position by applying a decent amount of force (*afraid to damage something if I apply any more force*).

It appears to operate without issue.

Should I call a professional to investigate this or just use it as is?

[image: with cover]

[image: under dead front]

Comment: Are you able to take the deadfront off and take a picture of the panel and breaker like that?  (you can turn off the main breaker first if you want).  That'll help us see if something actually broke or just shifted out of position.

Comment: I'd recommend you use the circuit only lightly, if at all, until you verify that everything is proper.  I'm guessing right now it's only halfway grabbing the bus stab, which is enough for things to work, but would burn up if a heavy load was applied.

Comment: @Nate S. I will remove the cover and take a photo when it is light out tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It went further to the center as long as it did not push the one to the right out of place don’t worry.

If you want to this is an easy fix but not needed in my opinion (I am a professional electrician).

There are screws that hold that face plate in position. Remove the lower screws first when you only have the top 2 left press in on that cover to hold it in place and remove the last 2 screws.

Pull the cover (called a dead face away) set it down.
Turn that breaker off then pry the handle towards the left and out they just snap out.
It may slide at this point prior to pulling out.

Look around at the wires if you see burned insulation let us know with another photo, if every thing looks good carefully put the panel cover back on I usually do the top 2 screws first opposite of removal put all the screws in make sure the breakers are all on some times you bump one and it will trip to the off position.
Always move a tripped breaker fully to the off position and back to on. Most when bumped or turned off will go to off but a light pull to off then it should move easily to the on position.

Give it a try, don’t touch any of the wires going into the main or any breaker these are the hots, I am sure there will be a U tube video on replacing a breaker if you want to watch it but it is a simple job you can do if you want but it is fine.

Comment: Ed, it actually went further away from the center. Is this still fine in your opinion? Because I like things neat and tidy I think I will go ahead and remove the dead face and reinsert it

Comment: Actually I can see it better on my computer it probably needs to be moved over but it is only a 15 amp breaker not an emergency. If you look at a back stab receptacle it is actually a sharp edge pushing the wire to another contact the pinch point on the breaker if touching will usually be fine. You can really fix this. To tell you the truth I regularly turn down this kind of work because the paperwork takes longer than the job. You might be able to find someone that will do it. Feel the breaker if it feels the same as the others (not hot) it’s not urgent but may be on the edge.

Comment: Yep, I'm glad I took your advice to open the panel myself. This took about 10 minutes, as someone who had never opened a panel before. Easily went back into place after removing the breaker

Comment: Great and now you have a new skill, adjusting that breaker is the same as replacing one, always turn the breaker off before removal or installing , but glad it worked!